# Any solid examples of jQuery-ActionScript communication?

Tags: jquery, actionscript

that involves event listeners.

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice integration point:

[jQuery SWFObject Plugin](http://jquery.thewikies.com/swfobject/)

Use the id you embed the swf with to get the object's reference in the dom (via jquery). Once you have the reference, you can call any method you have exposed to js on the object.

Expose methods to js in flash like so:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("methodName", method);
```

Calling js methods from flash is simpler:

```
ExternalInterface.call("jsMethodName") ;
```